# custom taxonomies on pages

Tags: custom-taxonomy

i need some help
how can i display custom taxonomies on selected pages?
i mean i have 3 custom taxonomies location,duration & courses
i have created three pages where i want to display the terms of these custom taxonomies,
i have displayed it on my posts by using function

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[terms]"); ?>
```

but same thing i want to make display on my pages also,
how can i do that??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a list of all terms in a taxonomy, you can call [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) and pass the `taxonomy` argument to get anything other than the categories:

```
wp_list_categories( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy'
) );
```

If you want to use a shortcode for this, so you can use it in your post content, use [`add_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode). This untested example code allows you to use `[taxonomy_terms]` or `[taxonomy_terms taxonomy=my-taxonomy]` in your content:

```
add_shortcode( 'taxonomy_terms', 'wpse4668_taxonomies' );
function wpse4668_taxonomies( $atts )
{
    // Sanitize our input
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your-default-taxonomy',
    ), $atts );
    // Don't echo the output, just return it
    $atts['echo'] = 0;

    return wp_list_categories( $atts );
}
```

Comment: thanks u helped me
but i have one more question,
i used the method wp_list_categories, but in the heading it is showing Categories where as it is my custom taxonomies, i want that to be printed
how can i do that?

Comment: @ntechi: In the linked codex page you can see that `wp_list_categories()` accepts a `title_li` parameter that you can set. You can even expand the shortcode handler to automatically get this from the definition of the taxonomy.

Comment: it is done
can you help me in a plugin
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/need-plugin-help

this is the question